# PhpStorm - Combine CSS files before minification using file watcher

Tags: phpstorm, bundling-and-minification

I have a project that has some CSS files in different folders and I want to combine them automatically into one final/live file.

During development I want them to be separate. 
I don't want to use `@import` inside the css files.

File watchers in PhpStorm sound to me like they should be able to to that. Because I need some GUI.

I'm not comfortable using the command line. But I got YUI Compressor up and running using this [step-by-step-guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/minifying-css.html). This setup compresses all my css files. Not really needed just want to compress one file.
I also learned that YUI Compressor can't combine files.

I want the following workflow on file change:

- Combine CSS files in the right order into one file
- Minify the one CSS file and safe it

Can someone list out:

- What node module to install and the command for that
- How to configure the file list and order. Any commands for that? File editing?
- How to start minification after finishing the combining

PS: If there is any application with a GUI that can do this on file change outside of PhpStorm it would also be an option. (CodePen doesn't support CSS, just SCSS and LESS)

Comment: You can setup multiple file watchers -- if they watch the same file(s) they will be executed one after another. As alternative -- create a batch/shell script that does such job (all tasks) and then just use it as File Watcher program. P.S. Have a look at gulp/grunt or any other task/build systems -- they are made for such tasks. IDE supports gulp/grunt -- so you can run their tasks any time you want manually ... or use it as file watcher .. or just use `watch` module to run them automatically in background outside of IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest using Grunt [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) task - it supports merging and minifying files. You can run the tasks using Grunt console (recommended), or configure it as file watcher